# How to sync variable between two WCF clients?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf

Currently I am working at a college project in which I'm developing WCF application.

I'm struggling with a problem to synchronize the variable between two clients.

Service code is like shown below:

```
public class SimpleHangmanService : IHangmanService
{
    public int playerCount = 0;
    public HangmanResponse GetCurrentPlayersCount()
    {
        HangmanResponse response = new HangmanResponse();
            
        playerCount += 1;
        response.count = playerCount;

        return response;
    }
}
```

I thought that if I make a service variable like provided above - if I run multiple clients, the **playerCount** would increment in every request of GetCurrentPlayersCount() method. Instead playerCount is different for every client (always set to 1).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this service/class singleton, same instance is used for all clients? Maybe new instance created per call. Print hashcode of it to verify, also for sync you need to lock variable before changing it. You better implement design pattern approach with data layer, the int should reside there, MVC or so.

Comment: Read up on the ServiceBehaviourAttribute in particular how the [InstanceContextMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode?view=netframework-4.8) property affects the service lifecycle. The default value is PerSession effectively giving you a service instance per client. From what you describe you would want to set this to Single. As @ilansch notes you should also deal with the thread unsafe way you are incrementing your counter now that the service object will be shared.